# Combining 3 columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to combine 3 columns, for example:

```
id  c_id    choice_a    choice_b        choice_c

1   1    Agra College   RBS College     St Jhones
2   2    Agra College   RBS College     St Jhones
3   3    Agra College   St Jhones       RBS College
4   6    Dyalbagh       Agra College    mahrana college
```

How would I approach this problem?

Comment: You have to add more details, like the db scheme, and should it be done with MySQL or with PHP ?

Comment: Please edit and correct your posting. What do you mean by "combine"? You're possibly looking for the CONCAT() function?!

Comment: Give us more information,so we can help you.Show us what have you tried,also you need to explain better,what you need..

Answer (score 1):

select CONCAT_WS(' ',col1 , col2,col3) from table

In CONCAT_WS() first argument is separator by which u want to separate columns values